# How to fetch songs of an album via albumID?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-music-player

Here is my code to get songs from SD card via albumID-

I'm receiving albumID as an intent from another glass and comparing it with the album_id of this class(AlbumsSong.java) and allow only those to be added to the array which satisfies the condition given in the code. For some reason it only shows me song of only one album. If you have doubts regarding the question please ask me!

```
public class AlbumsSong extends Activity {

RecyclerView recycler_albumSong;
AlbumsSongAdapter albumsSongAdapter;
ArrayList<SongInfoModel> s1 = new ArrayList<>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.album_details);

    long albumId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("album_id");
    recycler_albumSong = findViewById(R.id.albumsDetails_reyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recycler_albumSong.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recycler_albumSong.setHasFixedSize(true);



    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";


    Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);



    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));

                long album_Id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));


                if(album_Id==albumId){

                SongInfoModel s = new SongInfoModel(name, null, null, null, null, -1, null,null, albumId);
                s1.add(s);

                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        cursor.close();



    }




    albumsSongAdapter = new AlbumsSongAdapter(getApplicationContext(),s1);
    recycler_albumSong.setAdapter(albumsSongAdapter);

  }

}
```